# Jboss 4.2 war file using libraries of another war

Tags: java, jboss

Is there any way to make one war file (`w1`) use the libraries which is present in another war file (`w2`) in JBoss 4.2?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make an EAR, containing both WAR files with a common lib directory.

Comment: I agree that EAR is fine.. but we are looking for an alternate solution just by changing some config files, if possible

Answer (score 0):

You could put these libraries into the lib directory `jboss.server.lib.url`.

Read here: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/dirs.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. 

Actually i had already tried this and i am getting classNotFoundException